# numbering slides within part

Tags: beamer, sectioning, numbering

I would like to change the way the slides are numbered in Beamer and how they appear in the footline.

- I would like the slide numbering to be reset after each \part of the presentation.
- More specifically, I would like something  like the slide numbers to look like
  I.1, I.2,..., I.10, II.1,... where the roman numerals are the `\part` number.

I couldn't find how to do this in Beamer.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\insertpagenumber.\insertframenumber}

\AtBeginPart{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}

\begin{document}
\part{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\part{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```